# Are python questions appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

Python is so ingrained in Ubuntu. Would it be appropriate to ask python related questions on this forum? Or WHEN is it appropriate to ask questions about python? Where is a good place to ask python related questions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Development is on-topic here unless it really has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

I wouldn't object to Python questions here but you might get better service on Stack Overflow which is really *all* about programming. If your questions involve Ubuntu peculiarities or packaging a Python application, then we're probably the best bet. But again, this is on-topic on both sites.